# Django translate data on model save

Tags: python, django, translation

I need to translate the data automatically in the django admin.

I'm currently translating all the static text manually using django rosetta, to simplify the translation. What I need to do is translate all the data automatically using Microsoft translator API in the admin interface.

Lets assume I have a function that do the translation. Should I use django-modeltranslation with the translation function and override the save function for each model?

Any tips, modules, or code snippets that can help.

Comment: What is it that you need to translate ? Is it text that the user inputs ?

Comment: I need to translate all the charfields data that the user inputs in django admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the language you need to translate to and translate from is fixed, as in you don't intend the user to input data in several languages, then you could translate the data in your model save method:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):

    data = models.CharField()

    def save(self):
        """ Extension of parent save method """

        for name in ModelName._meta.get_all_field_names():
            field = getattr(name, ModelName, None)
            field = translate(field)

        super(ModelName, self).save()
```

Another option would be to do the translation in the input validation of the data, if it is a form:

```
class ModelNameForm(forms.Form):

    data = forms.CharField()

    def clean_data(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['data']
        return translate(data)
```

Comment: Lets say I have like 20 rows in the table, is there any way to do the translation without calling the translate on all fields one by one?

Comment: If you do this on the form the `clean()` would be a point to start, for example iterate over fields in the form `for key,value in self.cleaned_data: `

Comment: I updated my answer but I have not tried it, so I cannot assure it will work, but it's the idea.